# What is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)=\sin^2x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)=\sin^2x$?

I am not allowed to use anything fancy, just the process of mathematical induction and the basic rules for calculating derivatives. (I haven't studied the Leibniz rule for example)

So we have $$f'(x)=2\sin x(\sin x)'=2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x\\f''(x)=(\sin2x)'=\cos2x(2x)'=2\cos2x\\f'''(x)=(2\cos 2x)'=2(\cos2x)'=-4\sin 2x\\f^{(4)}(x)=-8\cos2x$$

Is it possible to make an assumption for the n-th derivate (that we will of course prove using induction) that doesn't include looking at different cases (I mean when $n$ is even and odd and etc)? In other words, I want to find a single formula parametrized with $n$ for the n-th derivative. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong at all with cases! But if you are allowed to use complex numbers then starting with $\sin^2 x=\frac12 -\frac14 \exp (ix) -\frac14 \exp(-ix)$ will give you a "single" formula, though it is less transparent than the one you've got here.

Comment: Hint: recall that $\sin^2 x=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos 2x}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $f(x)=\sin^2x=\frac12-\frac12\cos2x$, which makes writing successive derivatives a little more straight forward.  Recall that the cosine function is a quarter period phase shift of the sine function.

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac12-\frac{\cos2x}2\\
f'(x)&=\sin2x=\cos\left(2x-\frac\pi2\right)\\
f''(x)&=-2\sin\left(2x-\frac\pi2\right)=-2\cos\left(2x-\frac{2\pi}2\right)\\
f'''(x)&=4\sin\left(2x-\pi\right)=4\cos\left(2x-\frac{3\pi}2\right)\\
f^{(4)}(x)&=-8\sin\left(2x-\frac{3\pi}2\right)=-8\cos\left(2x-\frac{4\pi}2\right)\\\
&\vdots\\\
f^{(n)}(x)&=(-2)^{n-1}\cos\left(2x-\frac{n\pi}2\right)
\end{align}

The proof by induction is left as an exercise to the reader.